# How to run javascript in the browser remotely using WebTools`

Tags: webtools, webunit

I run the following commands to import the package:

```
Needs["WebTools`"];
Information["WebTools`*"]
```

Next I start my browser:

```
driver=StartDriver["Chrome"]
browser=TracePrint[StartBrowser[driver],_URLRead]
```

Next I open a webpage:

```
BrowserOpenPage[browser,"http://sqlzoo.net/"]
```

Next I want to click on the button:

```
wtClickElement[wtId["n-SELECT-basics"]]
```

The above use to work until the package was changed from `WebUnit` to `WebTools` but now i get some errors. So I try to do the same by running javascript directly on the browser.

```
BrowserExecute[browser,"
var button = document.getElementById('n-SELECT-basics');
button.click()
"]
```

But nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, if you are using Mathematica 11.3 then there is a built-in documented alternative to `WebTools`. See [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html).